# C++ Array Value

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix

I'm trying to figure out the value of A, B and C at the end of the program. When I try to cout using for loop, I get a whole list of values. I need a matrix format only.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int m = 3;
    int A[m] [m] = {};
    int B[m] [m + 1] = {};
    int C[m + 1] [m] = {};

    int counter = 0, k = 2;
    
    for (int i=1; i<=m; i++)
    {
        for (int j=1; j<=m; j++) 
        {
            A[i-1][i-1] = counter;
            B[i][j] = counter;
            C[j-1][j-1] = k;
        }
        counter++;
        k += 3;
    }

    //Printing C
    //get array columns and rows
    int rows =  sizeof C/ sizeof A[0]; 
    int cols = sizeof C[0] / sizeof(int); 
      
    // Print 2d Array
    cout << "your_array data "<<endl<<endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j)
        {
            std::cout << C[i][j] << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: there is no `cout` in the code you posted. Please incldue a [mcve] of the code that has the problem and actual and expected output in the question

Comment: `int A[m] [m] = {};` is not standard C++, but a compiler extention. use `std::vector` for variable sized arrays.

Comment: and please read this [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard). It should be `const int m = 3;`

Comment: @JHBonarius actually the size is constant `3`/`4`. no need for `std::vector`, it can be considered as typo

Comment: @idclev463035818 true.true. Still a mistake rookies often make ;)

Comment: In conventional C++ styling this should be `A[m][m]` with no spaces. The spaces here only serve to confuse.

Comment: I've edited the question to include the cout @idclev463035818

Comment: You'll have to do some work yourself to make the matrix. C++ is not matlab or python. You could use a library like Eigen or Boost UBLAS.

Comment: what output did you expect? What output did you get instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `A` and `C` are

```
int A[3][3] = {};
int C[4][3] = {};
```

Then you use

```
int rows =  sizeof C/ sizeof A[0]; 
int cols = sizeof C[0] / sizeof(int);
```

to get its size. Thats

```
int rows = 3; 
int cols = 4;
```

Then in the loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j)
    {
        std::cout << C[i][j] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

you have swapped values for `rows` and `cols`. `C` is `int C[4][3];` not `int C[3][4];`.

If you want to print several elements in one line you just need to move the `std::endl` to only add a new line only after a row:

```
for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j)
    {
        std::cout << C[i][j] << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Also note that this is not standard C++

```
int m = 3;
int A[m] [m] = {};
int B[m] [m + 1] = {};
int C[m + 1] [m] = {};
```

Read [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard) for more on that.

Answer (score -1):

`

```
 for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
 {
     for(j=0;j<cols;j++)
     {
         cout<<C[i][j]<<" ";
     }
     cout<<"\n";
 }
```

`
std:: is unnecessary because you have using namespace std;
You don't have to do endl because doing this you will print the next value on the next line. So you have to put another cout out of the nested loop.

Comment: you should explain your answer. Not just do his homework for him.